# Custom module cannot be loaded in wildfly-maven-plugin

Tags: wildfly, maven-plugin

I was trying to use `wildfly-maven-plugin` to deploy a EAR file. The EAR file has a dependency of a custom module which I have defined under /src/test/resources folder

I defined the `modules-path` in its configuration but it does not seem be picking it up.

```
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.wildfly.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>wildfly-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.1.0.Beta1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <modules-path>
                        <paths>
                            <path>${basedir}/target/wildfly-20.0.1.Final/modules</path>
                            <path>${basedir}/src/test/resources/wildfly-modules</path>
                        </paths>
                    </modules-path>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
```

Comment: The "module-path" (in configuration section) is only available for the run goal, not for the deploy one. See the doc: https://docs.jboss.org/wildfly/plugins/maven/latest/deploy-artifact-mojo.html

Comment: OK, but even I copied the files into the jboss modules/system/layers/base folder using maven-resources-plugin, it is still giving the same error.

Comment: What does your resource plugin configuration look like? You could use CLI commands to install the module.